# Does Group by with order by work ion Dql?

Tags: group-by, sql-order-by, dql

I am trying to execute a DQL (Doctrine) query that retrieve the latest answers of different doctors. 
we have table answer, member, Location (doctor table) and many other table connected to the doctor information. However I want to get the latest answer but the condition is one answer for a doctor. I do some search and know something about group by and order by dont work together !
Here is the query in DQL:

```
  $query = Doctrine_Query::create() 
  ->select("a.answer_id as answer_id,m.member_is as member_id,a.member_id") 
  ->from('Answer a') 
  ->leftJoin('a.Member m on m.member_id = a.member_id') 
  ->orderBy('a.date_added DESC') 
  ->groupBy('m.member_id') 
  ->limit(5);
```

---

but this query return undesirable results. Can anyone tell me where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you need to perform a subquery for that, which according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831985/selecting-from-subquery-in-dql), DQL does not support. However in that question it's suggested that you send a native query.