# Doctrine Query with subquery, order by, rand and group by

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

We have a table, from which we want to choose a random row, out of the last 1000 entries. However a user can enter multiple times, and independent of the amount of entries each user should have the same chance. This is currently solved by a native query (see below), which works. I was wondering if it's possible to translate this behaviour to a Doctrine statement, as we're planing to switch from MySQL to PostgreSQL in the future.

Current solution:

```
$conn = $this->em->getConnection();
$sql = 'SELECT tmp.username FROM (SELECT username, id FROM entries ORDER BY id DESC limit 1000) AS tmp GROUP BY tmp.id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I assume it's not possible. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243636/symfony2-doctrine-query-builder-as-a-subquery-in-from-clause

Comment: to bad. Well then we'll stick with the native query for now.