# line 0, col 51 near '(SELECT FLOOR(RAND()': Error: Class '(' is not defined

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi I'm trying to run this query with doctrine.

```
$query = $em->createQuery("select a from 
                                   (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 99999) AS random_num) a,
                                   'AdminBundle:Video' B
                                   WHERE B.VIDEO_KEY NOT IN (A.RANDOM_NUM)");
$nums = $query->getResult();
```

But instead I'm getting this error,

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 51 near '(SELECT FLOOR(RAND()': Error:
>   Class '(' is not defined.

It would be great help if someone can look into it...

Comment: In short words: DQL is not SQL.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with DQL ? :)

Comment: Here's almost the same qustion with great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831985/selecting-from-subquery-in-dql